# AllenNLP) Is there a way to set config for evaluation, epeicially for reader?

Tags: allennlp

I am new to allenNLP library.
In order to set args for `dataset_reader`, I want to set config for evaluation, like train (https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-template-config-files/blob/master/training_config/my_model_trained_on_my_dataset.jsonnet)

But I am not sure if there is a config file template for evaluation, like train, and the config file below works (where `train_data_path` and `trainer` parts are deleted.)

```
{
    "dataset_reader" : {
        // This name needs to match the name that you used to register your dataset reader, with
        // the call to `@DatasetReader.register()`.
        "type": "classification-tsv",
        // These other parameters exactly match the constructor parameters of your dataset reader class.
        "token_indexers": {
            "tokens": {
                "type": "single_id"
            }
        }
    },
    "validation_data_path": "/path/to/your/validation/data/here.tsv",
    "model": {
        // This name needs to match the name that you used to register your model, with
        // the call to `@Model.register()`.
        "type": "simple_classifier",
        // These other parameters exactly match the constructor parameters of your model class.
        "embedder": {
            "token_embedders": {
                "tokens": {
                    "type": "embedding",
                    "embedding_dim": 10
                }
            }
        },
        "encoder": {
            "type": "bag_of_embeddings",
            "embedding_dim": 10
        }
    },
    "data_loader": {
        // See http://docs.allennlp.org/master/api/data/dataloader/ for more info on acceptable
        // parameters here.
        "batch_size": 8,
        "shuffle": true
    },
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the exact same configuration file for training as for evaluation. If you do need different parameters in your dataset reader for eval, you can set the "validation_dataset_reader" field in addition to "dataset_reader".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@petew's answer is correct. `allennlp evaluate` does not read a configuration file. It uses the configuration file that is stored with the model. Run `allennlp evaluate -h` to get more info.

If you need the dataset reader to behave differently at evaluation time, use the `validation_dataset_reader` field in the configuration file. This will take effect both during training (for evaluations at the end of the epoch), and later, when you run `allennlp evaluate`.

Comment: I see, it seems if I want to use pretrained model, then there is no way to change config file alone.

Comment: I guess you want to set a `validation_dataset_reader` after the model has already been trained? You could unzip the model archive, change the config, and zip it back up.

Comment: Or maybe what you want to do is use `allennlp predict`?